# running tesseract js on an array of images

Tags: node.js, typescript, asynchronous, ocr, tesseract.js

i have a series of images , when trying to use tesseract on this array to read their text , i face this error:

```
Error opening data file ./eng.traineddata
Please make sure the TESSDATA_PREFIX environment variable is set to your "tessdata" directory.
Failed loading language 'eng'
Tesseract couldn't load any languages!
AdaptedTemplates != nullptr:Error:Assert failed:in file /src/src/classify/adaptmatch.cpp, line 196
trap!
trap!
AdaptedTemplates != nullptr:Error:Assert failed:in file /src/src/classify/adaptmatch.cpp, line 196
trap!
trap!
```

how can i solve this error?